# Validating Email Id using Regex in C#

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have an input string ("My Email id is abc @ gmail.com"). From the input string I need to validate Email id using Regex and need to replace it with (xxxxxxx).

I am using the below pattern but it doesn't work if the Email Id contains white Space.

`\\w+([-+.']\\w+)*@\\w+([-.]\\w+)*\\.\\w+([-.]\\w+)*`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want  to do is add whitespaces to word characters and maintain the original
regex integrity, it starts to get ugly:

```
 //    (?=\\s*\\w)[\\w\\s]+(?:[-+.'](?=\\s*\\w)[\\w\\s]+)*@(?=\\s*\\w)[\\w\\s]+(?:[-.](?=\\s*\\w)[\\w\\s]+)*\\.(?=\\s*\\w)[\\w\\s]+(?:[-.](?=\\s*\\w)[\\w\\s]+)*

 (?= \s* \w )
 [\w\s]+ 
 (?:
      [-+.'] 
      (?= \s* \w )
      [\w\s]+ 
 )*
 @
 (?= \s* \w )
 [\w\s]+ 
 (?:
      [-.] 
      (?= \s* \w )
      [\w\s]+ 
 )*
 \.
 (?= \s* \w )
 [\w\s]+ 
 (?:
      [-.] 
      (?= \s* \w )
      [\w\s]+ 
 )*
```